# No ghost image on drag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, drag-and-drop

I am currently working on building a CMS. 
In this CMS there is a builder-page where you can drag-and-drop elements into a canvas to create a website.
I use the plugins from jQuery (draggable, droppable, sortable) to expend functionality and make all the interaction possible.

Today a colleague of mine noticed that the ghost image on drag doesn't appear anymore. I do have a version of the system where it IS working, but this version is a month old and after trying for hours I can't seem to find what is causing this.

Note that there have been a LOT of changes in a month, and I have NO idea what causes the image to show on drag? Is it CSS/JS/HTML?

A piece of the HTML (+PHP) of the sidebar:

```
<li class="nav-parent">
        <a>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
            <span><?php echo 'basic_elements'; ?></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="children" style="display: none;">
            <li class="ab-nav-sub">
                <a class="left-panel-sub-container">
                    <i class="indicator fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    <?php echo $aTranslator['elements']; ?>
                </a>
                <div class="_elements" style="display: none;">
                    <div id="ab-nav-el_5" class="ab-nav-element ui-draggable information-popover" data-original-title="element_image_text_basic" title="<?php echo 'element_image_text_basic'; ?>" data-content="<div class='sidebar-tooltip'><strong>Plaatje/Tekst</strong><br>Veld voor een plaatje met tekst.</div><img src='tm_textimage.png'>">
                        <img src="/tm_textimage.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="">
                        <h2><?php echo $aTranslator['element_image_text_basic']; ?></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="ab-nav-el_7" class="ab-nav-element ui-draggable information-popover" data-original-title="element_video_text_basic" title="<?php echo'element_video_text_basic'; ?>" data-content="<div class='sidebar-tooltip'><strong>Video/Tekst</strong><br>Veld voor een video met tekst.</div><img src='tm_textvideo.png'>">
                        <img src="/tm_textvideo.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="">
                        <h2><?php echo $aTranslator['element_video_text_basic']; ?></h2>
                    </div>
```

There is too much CSS in too many files to post here...

Draggable JS:

```
 $('.ab-nav-element').draggable({
            appendTo: '.scroll-container',
            revert: 'invalid',
            cursor: "move", 
            distance: 50,
            revertDuration: 250,
            helper: 'clone',
            start: function(){
                $('.el-empty').addClass('el-receptive');
                elementName = $(this).data('original-title');
                elementTitle = $(this).attr('title');
                if($('.dashboard_container').children('.ab-builder-el.el-empty').length == 1){
                    $('.el-empty').addClass('huge');
                    $('.alert.alert-info').addClass('hidden');
                }
                //console.log(elementTitle);
            },
            stop: function(){
                $('.el-receptive').removeClass('el-receptive');
                elementName = null;
                $('.el-empty').removeClass('huge');
                $('.alert.alert-info').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
```

### Question

Can anyone give me advice on where to look for the change? 
I haven't changed anything on the way the jQuery plugins work, so that shouldn't be the cause of the problem.

Are there any styling attributes in CSS that I can try to overwrite?

Any advice is welcome, I would love to solve this issue today...

### Things I've tried

- Add the option `z-index` in the jQuery draggable options
- Add CSS: pointer-events:

  *{
      pointer-events: auto !important;
      -webkit-user-drag: auto !important;
  }

Comment: Would be easier to help if you could just provide any online link replicating your issue. But first thing you could check is if there is no CSS rule e.g: `.ui-draggable-dragging { visibility: hidden; }`

Comment: I understand that. But if I would be able to replicate the issue on a e.g. jsfiddle, I wouldn't need help trying to find where to look. There are too many files "working" on this page..

Comment: But does element reappear once you stop dragging it?

Comment: No there is never any image of the element visible. Not on any stage of the drag event.

Comment: At least post relevant code regarding your draggable plugin initialization. Maybe issue just comes from here

Comment: Draggable JS added

Comment: I'm sorry but without seeing minimalistic sample replicating issue and able to debug it, i cannot help you more, i'm afraid

Comment: Does this work on other browsers? Might be your browser updated'

Comment: Sadly it's not browserrelated, and @A.Wolff: I understand, thank you

Comment: Try with different type of "helpers"? Here's a demo of the types available: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#visual-feedback

Comment: Guys thank you so much for your help!!!
I was searching it all in the wrong area.

In my draggable initialize I have the option: appendTo. Someone deleted the .scroll-container....
Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a stupid fault:

The template was changed and thus the needed class `.scroll-container` was removed.
This is the class that the draggable clone gets appended to, so there was nothing to append to.

After changing the class to an available element e.g. `body` the clone appeared again.

Lots of thanks to the commentators!!!